# Get Id from Dynamically generated Images in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have some Dynamically Generated images on view using asp.net mvc4...and I have  to delete selected
images from from view...but i don't know how to pass id from view to controller
**controller code**:

```
public ActionResult imagelist(ShirtDb dg)
{
    List<ShirtDb> all = new List<ShirtDb>();

    using (patternChangeEntities8 et = new patternChangeEntities8())
    {
        all = et.ShirtDbs.ToList();
    }
    return View(all);
}
```

**View Code:**

```
@model List<patternchange.Models.ShirtDb>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Patterchange", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    @{
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 4)  {
    j = i;
    <tr>
        @while(j<i+4&&j<Model.Count())
        {
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].Image, 0, Model[j].Image.Length)" width="100" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Patterchange")'" @(Model[j].SId) />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[j].SId)
            <input type="submit" value="delete" />
        </td>
        j++;
        }
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    }
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code.in that I have created one JavaScript function which calls when button clicks and I have pass ID in that function at view time.

You can call your controller action via Ajax call

**View Code**

```
@model List<patternchange.Models.ShirtDb>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Patterchange", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    @{
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 4)  {
    j = i;
    <tr>
        @while(j<i+4&&j<Model.Count())
        {
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].Image, 0, Model[j].Image.Length)" width="100" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Patterchange")'" @(Model[j].SId) />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[j].SId)
            <input type="button" onclick="DeleteImage(@(Model[j].SId))" value="delete" />
        </td>
        j++;
        }
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    }
</table>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function DeleteImage(ID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Patterchange")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ id: '"+ID+"' }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { alert('Success'); },
            error: function () { alert('error');}
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
// Write your code for delete record by using id
            return View();
        }
```